# SMTP mail from .net applications

Tags: .net, email, smtp, exchange-server

We write applications that send out automated email alerts using SMTP.  We generally configure the applications to send to distribution groups within the company so we can easily configure recipients using exchange/outlook.  The issue is that currently we require that distribution groups receiving mail from our applications must allow senders that are not authenticated.  Every once in a while an exchange admin goes in a changes that so the groups requirement that all senders are authenticated.  Although that requirement is probably best practice, it prevents the group from receiving automated alerts from our apps.  How can we change our apps so they are concidered authenticated senders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your Exchange admins to provide you with the credentials of an account from which your code can send notifications.  Use these credentials in your code's [SmtpClient.Credentials Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).